# php authenticate to aws with aad account and mfa

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory

I start my AWS journey.

I need to develop a PHP application to list EC2 instances.
My aws accounts are linked (by the admin) to our Azure AD tenant, and I can logging to portal with my azure aad user/password and MFA.

I am able to create a local user and have a key/secret, but can I do the same code with my Azure AD user ?

```
<?php
require './sdk/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Sts\StsClient;

use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;

$IAM_KEY = '<KEY>';
$IAM_SECRET = '<SECRET>';

$stsClient = new StsClient([
   'version'     => 'latest',
   'region'      => 'eu-central-1',
   'credentials' => [
      'key'    => $IAM_KEY,
      'secret' => $IAM_SECRET,
   ],
]);

$rr = $stsClient->getSessionToken();

$accountToConnect = '0000000000';
$roleToAssume = 'MyRoleReadOnly';

$roleToAssumeArn = "arn:aws:iam::$accountToConnect:role/$roleToAssume";
$rr = $stsClient->assumeRole([
   'RoleArn' => $roleToAssumeArn, // REQUIRED
   'RoleSessionName' => 'session1', // REQUIRED
]);


$credentials = new Credentials(
   $rr['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
   $rr['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
   $rr['Credentials']['SessionToken']
);

$ec2 = new Ec2Client([
   'version'     => 'latest',
   'region'      => 'eu-central-1',
   'credentials' => $credentials,
]);

$res = $ec2->describeInstances();

echo "<pre>" .  json_encode($res['Reservations'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "</pre> \n";
```